# Как защититься от xss и sql иньекций

Tags: php, mysql, xss

Как защититься от уязвимостей типа xss или sql? Какие данные нужно обрабатывать и как ?

Comment: почитайте [этот сайт](https://www.owasp.org/), там много чего про это написано

Comment: Я английский очень плохо ) Хотелось бы просто узнать что фильтровать, а что не стоит )

Comment: Все что пришло со стороны должно быть проверено.

Comment: Фильтровать стоит абсолютно всё. отсутствие фильтра - собссна и есть иньекция, по сути.